# How to find words in a string that have consecutive letters in R language

Tags: r, regex, string

There is a problem that I do not know how to solve.

You need to write a function that returns all words from a string that contain repeated letters and the maximum number of their repetitions in a word.

Visually, this stage can be viewed with the following example:
`"hello good home aboba"` after processing should be `hello good`,  and the maximum number of repetitions of a character in a given string = `2`.

The code I wrote from tries to find duplicate characters and based on this, extract words from a separate array, but something doesn't work. Help solve the problem.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)   

text = 'tessst gfvdsvs bbbddsa daxz'
text = strsplit(text, ' ')
text

new = c()
new_2 = c()

for (i in text){
  
  new = str_extract_all(i, '([[:alpha:]])\\1+')
  if (new != character(0)){
    new_2 = c(new_2, i)
  }
}
new
new_2
```

Output:

```
Error in if (new != character(0)) { : argument is of length zero
> new
[[1]]
[1] "sss"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
[1] "bbb" "dd" 

[[4]]
character(0)

> new_2
NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```r
new <- unlist(str_extract_all(text, "\\p{L}*(\\p{L})\\1+\\p{L}*"))
i <- max(nchar( unlist(str_extract_all(new, "(.)\\1+")) ))
```

With `str_extract_all(text, "\\p{L}*(\\p{L})\\1+\\p{L}*")` you will extract all words containing at least two consecutive identical *letters*, and with `max(nchar( unlist(str_extract_all(new, "(.)\\1+")) ))` you will get the longest repeated letter chunk.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/AV3rAN):

```r
library(stringr)
text <- 'tessst gfvdsvs bbbddsa daxz'
new <- unlist(str_extract_all(text, "\\p{L}*(\\p{L})\\1+\\p{L}*"))
# => [1] "tessst"  "bbbddsa"
i <- max(nchar( unlist(str_extract_all(new, "(.)\\1+")) ))
# => [1] 3
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gn27Ea/1). *Regex details*:

- `\p{L}*` - zero or more letters
- `(\p{L})` - a letter captured into Group 1
- `\1+` - one or more repetitions of the captured letter
- `\p{L}*` - zero or more letters

Answer (score 3):

```
text = "hello good home aboba"

paste0(
  grep("(.)\\1{1,}", 
       unlist(strsplit(text, " ")), 
       value = TRUE),
  collapse = " ")

[1] "hello good"
```

Comment: Please add explanation for the regex.